# MvxListView not binding on the MvxItemTemplate

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm having an issue with my MvxListView and binding to it. Namely if I don't add an item template it binds just fine, but within the item template the bound data is no longer showing up.

**HelpView.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <Mvx.MvxListView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      local:MvxBind="ItemsSource HelpSections"
      local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_helpsection"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Item_HelpSection.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://scehmas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="40dp"
      local:MvxBind="Text Heading"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**HelpModel**

```
public class HelpModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Heading { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Heading;
    }
}
```

If I take off the ItemTemplate on the HelpView it displays the text from the ViewModel just fine, but when I add it back I just get blank lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is this will be some layout issue - perhaps try the hierarchy viewer to see if the list items are present.

Failing that perhaps also try changing `orientation`, tweaking heights, setting background colors, try binding to constant strings like "Text 'PlaceHolder'" etc. - or try a simple cell like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <TextView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:local="http://scehmas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="40dp"
      local:MvxBind="Text Heading" />
```

Once you've got something working, then you should be able to work your way back to a cell you actually want to display.

Comment: Still not sure what it was, but swapping down to a TextView only and then bringing back the LinearLayout worked.

Comment: For future viewers, check @renatoagomes answer.

Answer (score 4):

i think it was there at the **"scehmas"** it should be **"schemas"**

**Item_HelpSection.axml**

> ```
> <TextView
>  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>  xmlns:local="http://scehmas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
> ```